# Why scala fails type inference for f-bound polymorphism?

Tags: scala, type-inference, f-bounded-polymorphism

Simple example to illustrate the issue:

```
trait WTF[W <: WTF[W]] {
  def get : Int
}

trait Zero extends WTF[Zero] {
  override def get : Int = 0
}
case object Zero extends Zero

final case class Box(inner : Int) extends WTF[Box] {
  override def get : Int = inner
}

def printWTF[W <: WTF[W]](w : W) = println(w.get)

printWTF(Box(-1))
printWTF(Zero)
```

`Box` is ok, but `Zero` produces error:

```
WTF.scala:22: error: inferred type arguments [Zero.type] do not conform to method printWTF's type parameter bounds [W <: WTF[W]]
  printWTF(Zero)
  ^
WTF.scala:22: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Zero.type
 required: W
  printWTF(Zero)
           ^
two errors found
```

If I annotate type manually, it compiles:

```
printWTF[Zero](Zero)
printWTF(Zero : Zero)
```

The first line works as expected. I frequently encounter cases where type parameters could not be inferred from arguments. e.g. `def test[A](x : Int) : Unit`. The `A` type appears nowhere in the argument signature, so you should specify it manually.

But the latter is very obscured to me. I just added type cast that always is true, and miraculously the compiler learns how to infer method type parameters. But `Zero` is always of `Zero` type, why the compiler could not infer it without hints from me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Case object `Zero` has type `Zero.type` and is a subtype of `WTF[Zero]`. So when you call `printWTF(Zero)` the compiler infers `W = Zero.type` but `Zero.type <: WTF[Zero.type]` is false so compilation fails.

This more complicated signature on the other hand should work:

```
def printWTF[W <: WTF[W], V <: W](w: V with WTF[W]) = println(w.get)
```

And as a demonstration that this indeed infers the types correctly:

```
scala> def printWTF[W <: WTF[W], V <: W](w: V with WTF[W]): (V, W) = ???
printWTF: [W <: WTF[W], V <: W](w: V with WTF[W])(V, W)

scala> :type printWTF(Box(1))
(Box, Box)

scala> :type printWTF(Zero)
(Zero.type, Zero)
```

Comment: > Case object Zero has type Zero.type and is a subtype of WTF[Zero]

But general rule is that you could substitute any class entry with any subclass. The second line example does exactly the same. It does not change type signatures.

Comment: I don't think anyone knows the complete rules of type inference in Scala. All I know is that it doesn't retry for all super types of `Zero.type` in your example and that you have to help it a bit with some extra parameters like I did. And if you meant that you can substitute the `Zero` in `WTF[Zero]` with `Zero.type` you are mistaken because the `W` in `WTF` is invariant.

Comment: I didn't mean that `Zero` inside `WTF[Zero]` could be substitute. But anywhere, where expected `Zero` argument it could be substituted with `Zero.type` because function call is allowed to do so, `Function[Zero, T]` is subtype of `Function[Zero.type, T]`

Comment: @ayvango The compiler isn't going to try to arbitrarily up-cast to see if type bounds can be satisfied that way.